# CastError: Cast to ObjectId failed for value "categories"

Tags: reactjs, typescript, express

CastError: Cast to ObjectId failed for value "categories" (type string) at path "_id" for model "Product"
I have tried everything, but cant seem to get anywhere.

I want to show the categories in my navigation-bar, and get those categories from the database.

Backend:

```
productRouter.get(
  '/categories',
  asyncHandler(async (req, res) => {
    console.log('get categories')
    const categories = await ProductModel.find().distinct('category')
    res.json(categories)
  })
)
```

productModel:

```
@ModelOptions({ schemaOptions: { collection: 'products', timestamps: true } })
export class Product {
  public _id?: string

  @prop({ required: true })
  public name!: string

  @prop({ required: true })
  public slug!: string

  @prop({ required: true })
  public images!: string[]

  @prop({ required: true })
  public category!: string

  @prop({ required: true })
  public brand!: string

  @prop({ required: true, default: 0 })
  public price!: number

  @prop({ required: true, default: 0 })
  public countInStock!: number

  @prop({ required: true })
  public description!: string

  @prop({ required: true, default: 0 })
  public rating!: number

  @prop({ required: true, default: 0 })
  public numReviews!: number

  @prop({ required: true, default: [] })
  public reviews!: Review[]
}
```

Hook:

```
export const useGetCategoriesQuery = () =>
  useQuery({
    queryKey: ['categories'],
    queryFn: async () =>
      (await apiClient.get<[]>(`/api/products/categories`)).data,
  })
```

Rendering:

```
  const { data: categories, isLoading, error } = useGetCategoriesQuery()

...
...
              categories!.map((category) => (
                <ListGroup.Item action key={category}>
                  <LinkContainer
                    to={{ pathname: '/search', search: `category=${category}` }}
                    onClick={() => setSidebarIsOpen(false)}
                  >
                    <Nav.Link>{category}</Nav.Link>
                  </LinkContainer>
                </ListGroup.Item>
              ))
            )}
```

Answer (score 1):

I fixed the issue. Apparently I messed up the order of my route-handlers. Leading to another route-handler being called.